# VNC Server port is already in use

Tags: mac, port, vncserver

I'm on mac, my vnc server says the following:

> The port on which VNC Server is expecting to receive direct
> connections is in use by another program or service. For example, it
> may be that VNC-compatible Server software from a third party is
> already listening on this port.
>
> To resolve this issue, change the other program or service, or select
> a new, unique port for VNC Server.

The port is the default 5900, when I run

```
sudo lsof -i :5900
```

I see the following

```
COMMAND     PID USER   FD   TYPE            DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
launchd       1 root   24u  IPv6 0x1d049dbbfed525b      0t0  TCP *:rfb (LISTEN)
launchd       1 root   42u  IPv4 0x1d049dbc0174943      0t0  TCP *:rfb (LISTEN)
launchd       1 root   45u  IPv6 0x1d049dbbfed525b      0t0  TCP *:rfb (LISTEN)
launchd       1 root   46u  IPv4 0x1d049dbc0174943      0t0  TCP *:rfb (LISTEN)
vncserver 15090 root    6u  IPv4 0x1d049e08b3fa78b      0t0  UDP *:rfb
vncserver 15090 root    9u  IPv6 0x1d049e08b3faa9b      0t0  UDP *:rfb
```

I think it looks weird I have two vncservers? But anyway if I do

```
sudo kill -9 15090
```

and then

```
sudo lsof -i :5900
```

again it seems I still have two vncservers running, I have tried to turn off and restart vncserver, no difference.

How do I stop this blocking port 5900 so I can run  VNCserver,  it is really important for me to have the vnc access to this machine all the time, so I want to keep any problem like this from happening again if you have suggestions.

Comment: Did you perhaps enable Screen Sharing in macOS Preferences?

Comment: As @DanielB says - Mac has VNC implementation built-in, so a conflict is likely if you have anything in Sharing switched on which could also invoke VNC.

Comment: I have file sharing, remote login, remote management, and airplay receiver - should I turn off any of those (airplay receiver?) or should I perhaps change the port for vncserver?

Comment: I turned off airplay receiver, but still problem, so I just changed port to 5990 but I dislike that,  because naively I fear that if some app can take 5900 from vncserver then another one can take 5990. Is there a way to keep a port reserved for only one app and never allow another one to take it without having to ask me directly - open up that port!